# Nested Classes with Template

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

I'm having issues using a nested class with a template. The first snippet is provided, I just have to implement it.

```
 template <typename T>
class a {
   public:
      class b {
         public:
            func();
```

I thought the implementation would look something like this, but it isn't working.

```
    template<typename T>
    a<T>::b<T>::func(){}
```

Comment: Interestingly, gcc has clearer error message if you forget return type before implementation (I guess it makes it look like variable declaration): https://godbolt.org/z/9n1frG7M4. Fixing missing return type makes it less clear: https://godbolt.org/z/KG5vxxooo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much wrong with your start. You just need to to tie it together.

```
template <typename T>
class a {
public:
    class b {
    public:
        void func();  // return type missing
    }; // missing
}; // missing

template <typename T>
void a<T>::b ::func() {}
//          ^ not <T>
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M8e8q9oYT)